# Change of variables and making boundary data homogeneous in Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-functions, change-of-variable, elliptic-equations

Let us consider a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u +\lambda u= 0 & x \in \Omega \\
u = 1 & x \in \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
with $\lambda >0$.
Does it make sense to use the change of variables $v = u-\mathbf{1}_{\partial \Omega} $ to reduce the problem to the following one (with a source term but homogeneous boundary data)?
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta v + \lambda v = \Delta \mathbf{1}_{\partial \Omega} -\lambda\mathbf{1}_{\partial \Omega} & x \in \Omega \\
v = 0 & x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
How can this change of variable be made rigorous in the context of viscosity solutions?

This question is motivated by a [related post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407520/viscosity-solutions-of-deltas-u-0-in-omega-with-non-homogeneous-dat).

Comment: May be you have another problem in mind, but your first problem has only one solution $u(x) = 1$.

Comment: I agree with @Arctic Char, the only solution you have is $u(x)=1$ for all $x$. You need to have another type of boundary condition to have a more complex function.

Comment: @ArcticChar Good point. What if I consider $-\Delta u +\lambda u= 0$ instead?

Comment: @PC1 I've edited the question adding a lower order term in the equation

Comment: I would also say no it is not legitimate to consider $v=u-\mathbf{1}_{\partial\Omega}$ since $\mathbf{1}_{\partial \Omega}$ is not twice differentiable. Even you consider weak solution it is a.e. equal to zero so that goes nowhere either. I wonder why you don't just let $v=u-1$?

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially make this transformation on $\Omega$. Setting $v=u-1$ you obtain

$$-\Delta v + \lambda v = 0 \ \ \text{in } \Omega,$$

with $v=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. At this point you can extend $v$ to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Omega$ to be identically zero, but I'm not sure what gain you would get from this. The extension will be at most Lipschitz continuous, and definitely is not smooth.